# Androidでインターネット（サーバー上）のSQLiteデータベースの操作について

Tags: android, java, sqlite

AndroidでSQLiteを操作する方法はある程度分かるのですが、サーバー上のデータベースを操作（主に追加）をしたいのですがどうしたらいいのでしょうか。
URLで取得などすればいいのでしょうか。
MySQLなら出来なくはなさそうだったのですが、SQLiteは見つける事が出来ませんでした。
ご教授願います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQLなどはクライアントからネットワークなりを通してサーバーに接続するモデルなので、アプリケーションからネットワーク越しにDBに接続することができます。

しかしSQLiteの場合、アプリケーションに組み込まれたSQLiteライブラリが直接データベースファイルを操作しますから、サーバーという概念がなく、ネットワーク越しに接続するということもできません。

ですから、サーバー上のSQLiteデータベースに対して操作がしたいとなると、サーバー側に「SQLiteを操作するプログラム（API）」を自分で用意する必要があります。

「任意のSQLを受け取って実行し、結果をJSONで返す」といった形もありですが、実際には「○○を保存するAPI」「××を取得するAPI」といった形にして、SQLを隠ぺいしたり、データの前処理・後処理もサーバー側でやることが多いかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そうだったのですね。
SQLについてあまり理解できていませんでした。。。
とりあえず、MySQLについて勉強してみたいと思います。